# Add a white space/ header above navigation.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website, where there's a header or white space above navigation bar and I've been struggling with this for like three hours.. I'm using framework called "Foundation". I would really like to know what am I doing wrong so any help is appreciated! Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foundation-overwrite.css">
    <title>Svale Rejser</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="header">
</div>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <img src="pictures/logo_temp.png">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->

  </section>
</nav>


    <!--Scripts Here-->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

</body>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
/*NAVIGATION STYLING*/

.header{
    margin:auto !important;
    max-width:80% !important;
    max-height:30% !important;

}
.top-bar{
    clear:both !important;
    height:70px !important;
    font-family:Verdana,sans-serif !important;
    max-width: 80% !important;
    margin: auto !important;


}

.right{
    padding-right:50px !important;

}

.name{
    padding-left:50px !important;

}

.top-bar-section ul{


}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button){
    padding: 12px 15px !important;
}

.top-bar-section ul li > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 0 !important;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #333333; 
}

 .top-bar .name {
    height: 45px;
    margin-top:12px !important;
    font-size: 20px !important; 

 }
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly do you want the white bar? How big? We need some more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a working example, its hard to work out whats happening. I can your navbar is wrapped in a  with a class of .top-bar. Have you tried simply changing the margin? so it reads:

```
.top-bar{
clear:both;
height:70px;
font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
max-width: 80%;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}
```

That should give it a top margin of 20px.

You should also avoid using !important at all costs

Comment: thanks man, this worked! but why should I avoid important? I'm using the foundation framework, and I have my own css file, which is under the core css file and it still won't overwrite the current rules, so the only way is to write !important for me.. any advice?

Comment: Using !important can get you in trouble further down the line, you can't overwrite an important. If you having to use it, then your css isn't specific enough. If you are using a framework, and they have a rule for 'ul.list li a' then you should match that rule and overwrite their styles that way

Comment: Cheers mate. Basically copy exactly the same class name then?